Can I omit "it" in informal speech?
Instead of "coming from you, it means a lot" can I say "coming from you, means a lot"?

You can say what you like, if there's enough context for the person you're speaking to to understand it. Is there a reason you want to drop "it"? Did you hear this somewhere? See this question on similar deletion.

No, but you can do this: From you, it means a lot.

Voting to reopen since there's an interesting question about conversational deletion here. You can omit the "it" in "(It) means a lot coming from you" in informal speech.  So why can't you omit the "it" here?

Google shows plenty examples on social media (in one case quoted in a newspaper). Are they errors? How do you define an error in something so colloquial, other than by asking people "is this an error?"

You can, but it would not be correct gramatically.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

John Lawler indicates that grammaticality (note the spelling) isn't an issue in 'intimate conversational spoken English': 'Let me reiterate that this phenomenon only occurs in speaking English, and in other informal communication systems like email and t[e]xting that work like speech. It is not good formal written style, except for reporting dialog in a story.'
